# Is there any non JQuery JavaScript Library for Web tour that is supported by IE 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I tried using few of the javascript libraries like intro.js , Shephered, guider.js, hopscotch.js, tourist.js, crumble, pageguide, thundertour.js. But none of them is supported by IE 7.

Could anybody please suggest me a good javascript library(not a JQuery plugin) to make web tour. Or else some library to create interactive baloon tips which is supported by ie 7 and is not a JQuery plugin.

Comment: IE7 was released in 2006. Are you sure you need that? We are soon in 2016.  Most computers are replaced in less than 5 years (and typically 3 years)

Comment: Yes I require that. The users of the project that I am working on use IE 7. And they will not upgrade to any newer versions(not soon).

Comment: I hope they are paying you big bucks for that (you'll spend *lots* of your  developer's time). Or give up baloon tips and provide an old-fashion HTML4 interface (without Javascript)

Comment: If they do pay you well, you could as well implement one yourself. If not, change job asap.

Comment: `And they will not upgrade to any newer versions(not soon).`. This is bad :-(. Worse case, you might as well backtrack and look for the previous version of the library with the latest support for IE 7. However, looking for old version may break your app.